# Converting an Image to Data and Vice Versa

Tags: image, swift, sqlite, xcode7

I am using swift in Xcode and I need to convert an image to data in order to save it in SQLite db and also to convert the data object back to an image when I retrieve it from the database.
Any help please?
Simon

Comment: What do you mean with data? Do you want to transform the image to text (OCR?) or to a list of keywords? Or do you want to save the JPEG data to the database?

Comment: isn't better to save the image's URL in your DB ? and the image of the disk

Comment: @Bobj-C yes. core data would do it implicitly if the blob is big enough but for sqlite you should do it (IF the blob is 'big')

Answer (score 29):

**Swift 5.1 or later**

To convert from `UIImage` to `Data` you can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` if you need to reduce the file size.

```
extension UIImage {
    var jpeg: Data? { jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) }  // QUALITY min = 0 / max = 1
    var png: Data? { pngData() } 
}
```

To convert back to Image from `Data` you just need to use `UIImage(data:)` initializer:

```
extension Data {
    var uiImage: UIImage? { UIImage(data: self) }
}
```

---

Playground

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
if let jpegData = image.jpeg {
    print(jpegData.count) // 416318   number of bytes contained by the data object
    if let imageFromData =  jpegData.image {
        print(imageFromData.size)  // (719.0, 808.0)
    }
}
if let pngData = image.png {
    print(pngData.count)  // 1282319
    if let imageFromData =  pngData.image {
        print(imageFromData.size)  // (719.0, 808.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I convert this Image data in visual studio?

Comment: In swift 4.2, the conversion methods are simplified to image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) and image.pngData()

Comment: How to convert GIF image to data ?

Comment: I am not allowed to ask a question. Please explain how can I convert Image to data. The image is gif file, not png or jpeg.