# Use of unresolved identifier 'metadata'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code, but I have a problem, because it writes me Use of unresolved identifier 'metadata', Thanks in advance! I am a beginner in Xcode, so please explain well!

I got this out of in a youtube tutorial, from zero2launch!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage




class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Mailfield: UITextField!

    var selectedImage: UIImage?

    @IBAction func dismiss_onClick(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        ProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        ProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.handleSelectProfileImageView))
        ProfileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        ProfileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true





    }

    @objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


    @IBAction func SignUpButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Mailfield.text!, password: PasswordField.text! , completion:{(user: User?, error:Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let uid = user?.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gibble-2bed4.appspot.com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
            if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1){
                storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (matadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }

                let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                let usersReference = ref.child("users")
                let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)
                newUserReference.setValue(["username" : self.UsernameField.text!, "email": self.Mailfield.text!, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])


            })

            }


            })







    }

    }




extension SignUpViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       print("did Finish picking Media")
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
            selectedImage = image
            ProfileImage.image = image
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        print(info)

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialised matadata instead of metadata (which you want to use) in the closure in your following code (first line: "(matadata, error)"):

```
 storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (matadata, error) in
 if error != nil{
     return
 }

 let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
```

The metadata in the last line should be matadata or you have to change it in the first line.

Comment: In the tutorial he used metadata in both and I have another problem, the data isn’t JPEG it is .dms, so what to do?

Comment: Try to convert it maybe? Do you have access to the source?

Comment: To Save it to a database, you have to convert it into Data and then convert it back, to display it. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822241/converting-an-image-to-data-and-vice-versa